# Python 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this error:

```
>C:\Python27\python.exe ShodanHostSeeker.py
Made by Zaseth.
Your target IP: 19290334
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ShodanHostSeeker.py", line 12, in <module>
    openPorts = soup.find("meta", attrs={"name": "twitter:description"})["content"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am using Python 2.7.
My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
s = requests.Session()

print("Made by Zaseth.")
shodanURL = input("Your target IP: ")

r = s.get('https://www.shodan.io/host/' + str(shodanURL))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

openPorts = soup.find("meta", attrs={"name": "twitter:description"})["content"]
print(openPorts)

tableElements = [element.contents[0] for element in soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table"}).findAll("td")]
print(tableElements)

tableContents = [element.contents[0] for element in soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table"}).findAll("th")]
print(tableContents)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?
I am really lost and I already googled stuff.

Comment: Probably because `soup.find()` returned None.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille and how can I fix this?

Comment: it's because `openPorts` is `[]` so you can't get any content. However, I already suggested you API to use in the previous question of yours.

Comment: @Gahan What do you mean with openports is []

Comment: Why is `["content"]` on the next line, both in your traceback and in the posted code? Can you please correct your line endings if this text was wrapped in a terminal or console window?

Comment: I told you to refer [shodan API](https://shodan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it will take you few minutes and you will get a better solution.

Comment: @Gahan I see but I like to make my own.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is the way stackoverflow uses it. I got it on pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/raw/JmUQ0tkx

Comment: HTML code may change which will crash your code but API won't change like that. it's a safer way to proceed.

Comment: @Gahan Shodan has kept this format since launch.

Comment: by the way input() works in python3 in python2 it's raw_input()

Comment: @JavaSwd: no, that's how you posted it; I corrected the line endings.

Comment: @Gahan Thanks. Edited that to: shodanURL = raw_input("Your target IP: ")

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. Can you explain how to fix this issue?

Comment: Call `soup.find()`, withouth the `[...]` subscription to get the attribute. Test if the result is not `None`, and only then use `[...]` to get the attribute. Handle the `None` case too, there may have been an error downloading the page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are a hero. It fixed my issue. Thank you so much!